# How to get the contents of clipboard in a variable?

Tags: clipboard

If I copy something into the clipboard then use `var=Paste[];` I get `Null` in the `var` and the clipboard content is printed on the next cell. How do I get the content of the clipboard directly into the variable.

I have a basic text in my clipboard and want it stored as a string.

Moreover Windows 10's clipboard now supports multiple entries. Is there a way to select entries other than the last one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the *last* entry in clipboard you can use:

```
var = ToExpression[NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]][[1, 1, 1, 1]]]
```

This works in version 9 / windows 10 (64bit).

Comment: This allows to get only the last entry from the clipboard on Windows 10.

Comment: Good point, thank you @AlexeyPopkov.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps a partial answer; it shows that using ctrl+v rather than Paste[] allows an expression to be assigned to a variable as required.

As an example, enter

```
Red[]
```

Shows red box.

Select the box then use Paste from the context menu to copy it to the clip-board; then enter

```
x = Paste[]
x // FullForm
```

This shows x = Null.

Next, enter

```
y=
```

then type ctrl+v

This gives the red box as expected; enter

```
y // FullForm
```

This gives RGBColor[1,0,0], which shows that the expressions has been passed to y as required.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, there is an undocumented function for this purpose:`PastContent[]`

Comment: There is no built-in function `PastContent`, at least in version 12.3.1: ``Names["*`*Past*Content*"]`` returns empty list. Probably you refer to this: https://mmaqa.com/qa/1731/mmaexcelmma?show=1773#a1773

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Aha..Life is hard, and I don't remember what I ever did at all. That link you quoted is exactly one of the questions I answered myself a few years ago. BTW, you're Chinese? How did you find out about that community?

Comment: No, I've found this link [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239280/how-do-i-make-clicktocopy-copy-some-text-rather-than-string/239287#comment604160_239287).