# How do I make ClickToCopy copy some text rather than string?

Tags: clipboard, copy-as

Consider the following example:

```
ClickToCopy["display text","file name"]
```

When I click the `display text` I get `"file name"` rather than `file name` without the quotes. Which doesn't serve my purpose of quick file name access. So when I copy to some location I have to manually remove the quotes.

What should I do to make it copy the actual `Text` inside the `String`?

Comment: `ClickToCopy["display text",Defer[ file name]]`?

Comment: .. or `ClickToCopy["display text",ToExpression["file name",StandardForm, HoldForm]]`?

Comment: @kglr the text needs to be copied into a different program. So if I use the second one I get \!\(TagBox[RowBox[{"file", " ", "name"}],HoldForm]\) which is not correct.

Comment: The first one works by modifying to `ClickToCopy["display text", 
 Defer[Evaluate[ToExpression["file name"]]]]` and produces the text of the string on copy.

Comment: But the issue with this is that the file names have initials like `Alex E` so if I evaluate `ClickToCopy["display text", Defer[Evaluate[ToExpression["Alex E"]]]]` I get `Alex \[ExponentialE]` which is not correct.

Comment: try if  `Button["display text",CopyToClipboard["file name"], Appearance->None]` works?

Comment: Thank you it works but again it is still a workaround. I really liked the `ClickToCopy` appearance on hover and click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `CopyToClipboard`:

```
Button["display text", CopyToClipboard["file name"], Appearance -> Frameless]
```

[`CopyToClipboard >> Scope`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CopyToClipboard.html)

> #### *"Copying a string copies the contents of the string."*

```
Column @ MapThread[Button[#, CopyToClipboard @ #2, Appearance -> Frameless] &, 
    {{"display text 1", "display text 2"}, {"file name", "Alex E"}}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is really nice and will do the job. But I wish there was a way to get `ClickToCopy` to work. I really liked the `ClickToCopy` appearance on hover and click. I will raise this issue in the next SW Livestream. They could easily make the click to copy the content of the string rather than the string object via some option perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just use [`RawBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RawBoxes), e.g.:

```
ClickToCopy["display text", RawBoxes@"file name"]
```

Comment: This is the way. Though I must admit that this is a bit obscure!

Answer (score 1):

The style definition of `ClickToCopy` can be found in the following stylesheet

```
FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","StyleSheets","Core.nb"}
```

and uses `CopyToClipboard`

```
...
ButtonBox[
    ...
    CopyToClipboard[Cell[BoxData[#2],"Input"]]
    ...
]
...
```

where the double quotes come from.

Hence we can try to define a new function by slightly modifying `ClickToCopy`, and this has almost been done.
The undocumented function `` CloudObject`Private`customClickToCopy `` has essentially the same definition but different options as `CopyToClipboard`,

```
Needs["CloudObject`"];
CloudObject`Private`customClickToCopy[#,Hold[#]]&@"test"
```

[image]

With slight efforts we have

```
clickToCopyText[displayedText_] :=
    clickToCopyText`kernel[displayedText,displayedText];
clickToCopyText[displayedText_,copiedText_] :=
    clickToCopyText`kernel[displayedText,copiedText];


clickToCopyText`kernel[displayedText_,copiedText_] :=
    Mouseover[
        clickToCopyText`makeClickToCopyOverlay[displayedText,None],
        DynamicModule[{Typeset`boxobj,Typeset`cellobj},
            EventHandler[
                Button[
                    clickToCopyText`makeClickToCopyOverlay[displayedText,clickToCopyText`aliceBlue],
                    CopyToClipboard@copiedText;
                    NotebookDelete@Typeset`cellobj;
                    Typeset`cellobj =
                        MathLink`CallFrontEnd@FrontEnd`AttachCell[
                            Typeset`boxobj,
                            Cell@BoxData@TemplateBox[{"Copied"},"ClickToCopyTooltip"],
                            {1,{Center,Bottom}},
                            {Center,Top},
                            "ClosingActions"->{"ParentChanged"}
                        ],
                    Appearance->FrontEndResource["FEExpressions","SuppressMouseDownNinePatchAppearance"],
                    BaseStyle->{},
                    Alignment->{Left,Automatic},
                    DefaultBaseStyle->{},
                    BaselinePosition->Baseline,
                    FrameMargins->0,
                    Method->"Preemptive"
                ],
                {
                    "MouseEntered":>(
                        Typeset`cellobj =
                            MathLink`CallFrontEnd@FrontEnd`AttachCell[
                                Typeset`boxobj,
                                Cell@BoxData@TemplateBox[{"Copy"},"ClickToCopyTooltip"],
                                {1,{Center,Bottom}},
                                {Center,Top},
                                "ClosingActions"->{"ParentChanged"}
                            ]
                    ),
                    "MouseExited":>NotebookDelete[Typeset`cellobj]
                },
                PassEventsDown->True
            ]//MouseAppearance[#,"LinkHand"]&,
            Initialization:>(
                Typeset`boxobj = EvaluationBox[]
            ),
            UnsavedVariables:>{Typeset`boxobj,Typeset`cellobj},
            BaseStyle->{Editable->False}
        ]
    ];

clickToCopyText`makeClickToCopyOverlay[text_,bgColor_] :=
    Framed[
        text,
        Background->bgColor,
        FrameStyle->bgColor,
        "BoxExpandable"->True,
        BaseStyle->{},
        DefaultBaseStyle->{},
        Alignment->{Left,Automatic},
        BaselinePosition->Baseline,
        FrameMargins->0
    ];

clickToCopyText`aliceBlue = N@RGBColor[{232,243,255}/255];
```

Now let's test,

```
testString=(SeedRandom[1];RandomWord[20]//StringRiffle)

test={{"clickToCopyText",clickToCopyText@testString},{"ClickToCopy",ClickToCopy@testString},{"plain",testString}};
```

```
test//Grid
```

[image]

and the pasted text contains no double quotes as expected.

### Drawback

I take several hours on the compatibility of `clickToCopyText|ClickToCopy` with `Dataset`, but failed,

```
test//Dataset
```

[image]

The text font can be easily fixed by the options

```
BaseStyle->{FontFamily->"Source Sans Pro",FontSize->14,FontWeight->Plain}
```

But for `ClickToCopy`, sometimes (maybe according to the type system of `Dataset`) there are double quotes appearing in the dataset by the cell option

```
ShowStringCharacters->True
```

For my `clickToCopyText`, the text will be hidden if too long, and I have no idea how to fix it by `clickToCopyText` or options of `Dataset`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, for reference only, you can use the following method to paste the contents of the pasteboard to MMA:

```
   PastContent[] := 
     NETLink`NETBlock[
      Block[{img, width, Width, height, Height, LockBits, PixelFormat, 
        Format24bppRgb, stride, Stride, Scan0, totalB, byte, intPtr, data,
         UnlockBits, lock}, Needs["NETLink`"]; NETLink`InstallNET[];
       NETLink`LoadNETType["System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard"];
       Which[Clipboard`ContainsText[], 
        If[Clipboard`GetText[] // 
          StringStartsQ[#, "\\!\\("] && StringEndsQ[#, "\\)"] &, 
         ToExpression[Clipboard`GetText[]], Clipboard`GetText[]], 
        Clipboard`ContainsImage[], 
        NETLink`LoadNETType /@ {"System.Drawing.Rectangle", 
          "System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode", 
          "System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal"};
        img = Clipboard`GetImage[];
        width = img[Width]; height = img[Height];
        lock = 
         img[LockBits[Rectangle`FromLTRB[0, 0, width, height], 
           ImageLockMode`ReadWrite, img[PixelFormat][Format24bppRgb]]];
        stride = Abs[lock[Stride]]; intPtr = lock[Scan0];
        totalB = stride*height;
        byte = NETLink`NETNew["System.Byte[]", totalB];
        Marshal`Copy[intPtr, byte, 0, totalB];
        data = NETLink`NETObjectToExpression[byte];
        Marshal`Copy[byte, 0, intPtr, totalB]; img[UnlockBits[lock]];
        Image[
         Map[Reverse /@ Partition[#, 3] &, 
          Partition[data, width*3, stride]], "Byte"], 
        Clipboard`ContainsFileDropList[], 
        NETLink`NETObjectToExpression[Clipboard`GetFileDropList[]]]]]

PastContent[]
```

I think you should post the code of function `ClickToCopy` for us to revise.

Comment: [`ClickToCopy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClickToCopy.html) is built-in.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for your reminding. I use version 12.1, and this function is a new function in version 12.2.

Comment: This isn't an answer, then why not post a comment with the link to this function?: https://mmaqa.com/qa/1731/mmaexcelmma?show=1773#a1773

Comment: @xzczd Sorry, this is my negligence. Thank you for your supplementary information.