# RawBoxes in ClickToCopy adding spaces after escaped characters

Tags: string-manipulation, latex, boxes

I'd like to use ClickToCopy to display a matrix equation, and have its TeX form be copyable. I started with something like

```
ClickToCopy[M == IdentityMatrix[2], 
 ToString@TeXForm[M == IdentityMatrix[2]]]
```

but then the copied text is a String and not something I can just paste into a tex file:

```
"M=\\left(\n\\begin{array}{cc}\n 1 & 0 \\\\\n 0 & 1 \\\\\n\
\\end{array}\n\\right)"
```

So, following advice [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239280/how-do-i-make-clicktocopy-copy-some-text-rather-than-string), I added `RawBoxes`:

```
ClickToCopy[M == IdentityMatrix[2], 
 RawBoxes@ToString@TeXForm[M == IdentityMatrix[2]]]
```

This is much closer to being correct, but now I get

```
M = \left (
   \begin {array} {cc}
         1 & 0 \\
       0 & 1 \\
     \end {array}
    \r ight)
```

In the last line, "\right" gets an unwanted space. Looking at other examples, this behavior seems to be connected with the backslash, but I'm not sure exactly what makes it happen.

Is there (a) a way of fixing the original ClickToCopy without RawBoxes, or (b) a way to fix this behavior in RawBoxes?

Comment: There is no space. How and where have you pasted it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a problem when trying to paste it outside of Mathematica when there is indeed a space after `\r`.

A workaround using `Button` and `CopyToClipboard`:

```
Button[M == IdentityMatrix[2], 
 CopyToClipboard@TeXForm[M == IdentityMatrix[2]], 
 Appearance -> "Frameless"
]
```

**Update:**

A better version of the above code that makes the output visually same as if `ClickToCopy` was used, including the mouse-over label `Copy to clipboard`.

```
Button[ClickToCopy[
  Style[M == IdentityMatrix[2], {"Output", "StandardForm"}], Null], 
 CopyToClipboard@TeXForm[M == IdentityMatrix[2]], 
 Appearance -> "Frameless"]
```

---

[image]

[image]

After clicking the output and pasting:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to avoid missing out on the nicer look-and-feel of ClickToCopy, but as far as I can tell there's no way to get ClickToCopy to work the way I need, so this is the best move. It would be great if ClickToCopy were updated to include an "External" option, where e.g. strings are copied to the clipboard raw instead of as Wolfram input.

Comment: @srossd: Yes `ClickToCopy` is primarily made for using to paste the copied code into Mathematica. I updated my answer with a better code that resembles the appearance and functionality of `ClickToCopy`.

Comment: Oh, that is clever, thank you!