# Using Mathematica, can the contents of a tooltip be written to the paste buffer?

Tags: graphics, tooltip

I have an application where tooltips are used to give information on each of a graphical array of objects. I subsequently want to use the content of the tooltip to create any particular object of interest. If the contents of the tooltip can be written to the paste buffer then I should be able to do this easily. But I haven't been able to figure out how to do this...

Comment: I'm not sure Mathematica is the best tool for this. Depending on your operation system & the application you are using, there is probably a more direct way to extract the contents of a displayed tooltip, see e.g. [this discussion](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/53672-get-the-text-content-of-a-tool-tip-window/) (unless of course your "application" is a Mathematica notebook)

Comment: Thanks for that, but my application is indeed a Mathematica notebook!

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't provide the code for your application, let's use this as example:

```
SeedRandom@1
Graphics[
 {
  AbsolutePointSize@10,
  Tooltip[Point@#, #] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}]
  }
 ]
```

[image]

If we now want to be able to copy something to the clipboard, we can use [`EventHandler`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler.html) and [`CopyToClipboard`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CopyToClipboard.html)

```
SeedRandom@1
Graphics[
 {
  AbsolutePointSize@10,
  EventHandler[
     Tooltip[Point@#, #],
     {"MouseClicked" :> CopyToClipboard@#}
     ] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}]
  }
 ]
```

Now, clicking on a point puts its coordinates into the clipboard. Note that it doesn't need to be a `Graphics` expression, `EventHandler` can be used anywhere where `Tooltip` works.

Comment: Thanks very much for that - that looks very promising. It will take me a little while to apply it to my application. Unfortunately, my application does not lend itself to giving a brief example - I will see if I can think of something similar to illustrate it.

Comment: This works very well and is simple and versatile. Thank-you very much. One disappointment, which is down to Mathematica, not your Answer, is that Paste[] does not work as expected, so if you write x=Paste[], x is set to Null. This has been noted elsewhere [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58614/understanding-paste-and-how-to-get-a-string-from-the-clipboard-to-use-with-im) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199830/how-to-get-the-contents-of-clipboard-in-a-variable?rq=1).