# Copy value of Tooltip from AnatomyPlot3D

Tags: plotting, tooltip, anatomy

When plotting anatomy data with

```
AnatomyPlot3D[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftIndexFinger"], Method -> {"Tooltips" -> True}]
```

the respective tooltips are shown at the mouse pointer location

[image]

Is there a way to copy the content of the selected tooltip to the clipboard and paste it to another cell? I have seen other answered questions (like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245557/using-mathematica-can-the-contents-of-a-tooltip-be-written-to-the-paste-buffer)), but there tooltips were generated for each item/entity separately. When plotting an AnatomyPlot3D with the tooltip method all tooltips are already included.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do post processing on the anatomy plot with something like

```
ReplaceAll[
    AnatomyPlot3D[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftIndexFinger"],
        Method -> {"Tooltips" -> True}
    ],
    Tooltip[a_, b_] :> EventHandler[Tooltip[a, b],
        {"MouseClicked" :> CopyToClipboard[ToString[b, InputForm]]},
        PassEventsDown -> True
    ]
]
```

Clicking and dragging will move the 3D object without copying anything. Clicking an object with a tooltip and not dragging will copy the tooltip to the clipboard.

Comment: I tried that but it put a `TextCell` in my clipboard rather than a string.

Comment: How exactly do you get a string?  Do you paste in between cells, creating a new cell, or within an already existing cell?  I get different results from those two, and only one of them is usable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rXyc.png

Comment: I pasted between cells. It created an input cell with a string like `Cell["\"foo\"", "Input"]` and not a proper input cell with `BoxData` like `Cell[BoxData["\"\<foo\>\""], "Input"]`. If I paste in an existing cell, I get an inline cell.  So I guess `ToString` is better.

Comment: Hi Jason, this works great! Combined with a snippet from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16925/extracting-the-coordinate-of-a-particular-point-of-interest-from-a-listplot I can display the selected structures right below the plot: clicks = {};
Column[{ReplaceAll[
   AnatomyPlot3D[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftIndexFinger"], 
    Method -> {"Tooltips" -> True}], 
   Tooltip[a_, b_] :> 
    EventHandler[
     Tooltip[a, 
      b], {"MouseClicked" :> 
       AppendTo[clicks, ToString[b, InputForm]]}, 
     PassEventsDown -> True]], Dynamic[clicks // TableForm]}]