# Output of code generated by CellPrint goes to the end of notebook

Tags: bugs, front-end, notebooks, output

**Bug introduced in 3.0 and persisting through 13.0.1. Wolfram Cloud is not influenced.**

---

This is an issue raised up when I use the function [`importCode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3537/1871), the following is a simplified sample reproducing the issue. First execute the following line to create 2 cells:

```
Scan[CellPrint@Cell[#, "Input"] &, {"1\n2", "3"}]
```

Then execute the first generated cell, you'll see:

[image]

As we can see, the output `2` goes to the end of notebook unexpectedly. (If you go on executing the cell containing `3`, the `2` in output cell is *eaten*. This is expected, though. ) Is this a bug or by design? Any work-around? (Because of this, the function `importCode` isn't working well on code block with multiple outputs for the moment. )

Comment: Did you evaluate the output of your code? It seems so because of the `In[]` tags, but you don't say explicitly. I get this output from your code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5TkX.png. I get this when the output is evaluated: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI4Mw.png. I get no `2` at all. I question whether `Cell["1\n2", "Input"]` represents proper input, the [cell expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsJr7.png) does not contain `BoxData`. (I don't know the answer, but I ran into trouble with recently.)

Comment: If you enter `1`, return, `2`, I get a cell with a cell expression like this: ``Cell[BoxData[{"1", "\[IndentingNewLine]", "2"}], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.865240719373975*^9, 3.8652407198856688`*^9}}]``, with the input split into a list of strings.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah I evaluate the generated cell. Sorry for the vagueness. Clarified. One should not evaluate the second cell containing `3`, otherwise the `2` in output cell will be eaten.

Comment: I ran into the cell expression trouble here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269750/copy-value-of-tooltip-from-anatomyplot3d/269752#comment672979_269752

Comment: Yeah, I just figured out what I did differently. :) Thanks for showing the steps you took. I get the `2` taking the same steps as you. It will be interesting what WRI's answer is.

Comment: Those are relevant: [John Fultz comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149558/how-to-make-the-result-of-inputform-balance-the-bracket#comment403087_149583).

Answer (score 9):

I don't have full insight so I am encouraging FE team to answer or update this one.
Currently I can only more or less explain what is going on but not why/what was the original idea.

**The rule of thumb is**: `CellPrint` should be used to generate output-ish cells. Use `NotebookWrite` for a full control.

Confirmation of the rule are those comments by [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149558/how-to-make-the-result-of-inputform-balance-the-bracket#comment403087_149583)

---

**Explanation**

`CellsPrint` adds `CellAutoOverwrite` and `GeneratedCell` options to what it creates so we can already see that those options together with Input style will be problematic.

FE actions when kernel returns an evaluated cell's expression are (based on rough experiments):

1. Delete all subsequent cells which are `CellAutoOverwrite` but not `Evaluatable`.
2. Insert Cell
3. Move selection after subsequent `GeneratedCell`s. (Notice the Output cells are GeneratedCells by default)

Sounds reasonable. Maybe you could think about something simpler. Maybe the 3rd rule should exclude `Evaluatable` again, I don't know, but keep in mind that it should be 30y backward compatible and it has to handle issues like the bug mentioned by JF in the linked comment.

Having those rules **explains OP problem**, `3` is not good enough to be deleted (has Evaluatable) but selection will move past it (GeneratedCell). It looks weird but is solved with `NotebookWrite` or if we only print output-ish (non Evaluatable) cells with `CellPrint`.

[Alexey problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149558/how-to-make-the-result-of-inputform-balance-the-bracket#comment403087_149583) is explained as well: Text cell will be deleted because it has CellAutoOverwrite and does not have Evaluatable settings.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much my view.  The issue here is that we made something very general and powerful that both takes arbitrary cells without constraints, but also tries to act like `Print` (in the way that cells can be regenerated and replaced).  Those two goals cannot be entirely resolved without conflict, and we erred toward the "arbitrary cells without constraints" side of that conflict, which gives users more power but also rope with which to hang themselves.

Answer (score 4):

I reproduce this behavior with versions 5.2, 8.0.4, 12.3.1 and 13.0.1 on Win10 x64.

I would count this as a long-standing FrontEnd bug. An extended example:

```
CellPrint /@ {
   Cell["\"First output from Cell#1\"\n\"Second output from Cell#1.  Whoops! How did I get here ???\"", "Input", CellLabel -> "Cell#1"],
   Cell["I'll disappear after evaluation of the previous cell!", "Text",  CellLabel -> "Cell#2"],
   Cell["3", "Input", CellLabel -> "Cell#3"]};
```

After evaluation of the first printed input cell with label `"Cell#1"`, the `"Text"` cell  with label `"Cell#2"` disappears. And the second output from `"Cell#1"` is unexpectedly printed after `"Cell#3"`!

[image: screen record]

As a workaround I can suggest using `NotebookWrite` instead of `CellPrint`:

```
NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], #] & /@ {Cell["1\n2", "Input"], 
   Cell["I won't disappear after evaluation of the previous cell!", "Text"], 
   Cell["3", "Input"]};
```

[image: screenshot]

---

### Further observations

It's also worth noting that the documentation for [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint.html) contradicts its observed behavior. In particulat, it states (in the very first section under the function name):

> `CellPrint[expr]`
>
> inserts `expr` as a complete cell in the current notebook just below the cell being evaluated.

However, by default `CellPrint[expr]` inserts `expr` *below the last cell generated* by the cell being evaluated (and in this sense behaves exactly like `Print`):

```
"Main output"
Print["First Print"]
CellPrint[Cell["First CellPrint", "Input"]]
Print["Second Print"]
CellPrint[TextCell["Second CellPrint", "Text"]]
```

[image: screenshot]

Something similar to the documented behavior happens when we print cells with `GeneratedCell -> False` option. But as one can see, in this case `CellPrint[expr]` inserts `expr` *below the last cell with `GeneratedCell -> True`* generated by the cell being evaluated:

```
"Main output"
Print["First Print"]
CellPrint[TextCell["First CellPrint", "Input", GeneratedCell -> False]]
Print["Second Print"]
CellPrint[TextCell["Second CellPrint", "Text", GeneratedCell -> False]]
```

[image: screenshot]

Hence we also have a Documentation bug.

To summarize the above observations:

**`CellPrint[expr]` inserts `expr` below the cell being evaluated after the last cell with `GeneratedCell -> True` above the next cell with `GeneratedCell -> False`, even if the latter was generated during current evaluation.**

Or shorter (official documentation style):

**`CellPrint[expr]` inserts `expr` just above the next cell with `GeneratedCell -> False`, or at the end of the evaluation notebook.**

However, in order to fully understand the results of `CellPrint`, one must take into account the general behavior of the FrontEnd when it receives the evaluation result (described in the "Explanation" section of the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269996/280) by [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba)). In the first place, one should pay attention to the fact that as the first step the FrontEnd *deletes* all subsequent cells which have `CellAutoOverwrite -> True` but not `Evaluatable -> True`.

Comment: Same behavior in v4: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C43Al.png v3 is broken in a slightly different way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjmlk.png So, it's broken from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I did notice that we can override `GeneratedCell` and `CellAutoOverwrite` by providing them as options in `Cell`. I don't have experience in this domain, but it seems giving `False` to both of them on all 3 cells solves the problem (for some reason it prints in reverse order, so a `Reverse` is also needed).

Comment: @BenIzd I think you're right (main part). As for the parenthetical, when `CellPrint` is evaluated it "inserts expr as a complete cell in the current notebook just below the cell being evaluated" (see docs).  So the last `CellPrint` is the first thing under the evaluated cell.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I added the "Further observations" sections which shows that this docs statement contradics the observed behavor of `CellPrint`.