# How to generate input cells whose code is determined dynamically?

Tags: notebooks, cells, input, code-generation

Following [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144896/how-to-generate-an-input-cell), I want to use code to generate an input cell with new code. However, unlike the linked post, I want my code to dynamically determine the new code to be printed in the input cell.

The use of `Defer` is making this difficult. For example, the following works:

```
makeImportCell[filename_] := 
   CellPrint[ExpressionCell[
       Defer[data = Import[filename]], "Input"]]
```

`makeImportCell["myData.txt"]`

Output (as an input cell):

`data = Import["myData.txt"]`

But if I want the function to manipulate the string `filename`, it breaks:

```
makeImportCell[filename_] := Module[{file},
  file = filename <> ".txt"; 
  CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Defer[data = Import[file]], "Input"]]]
```

`makeImportCell["myData"]`

Output (as an input cell):

`data = Import[file$45844993]`

I'd also like to use `If` statements based on some other variables to alter the code that gets generated, but if I put any `If`s into `Defer`, they'll be left unevaluated. Maybe the best solution would be to have the function construct a large string containing exactly the code I want to print, and then print this string as input code rather than a string. But I can't figure out how to do this.

---

I just realized I could use

```
makeImportCell[filename_] := 
   CellPrint[ExpressionCell[
       Defer[data = Import[filename <> ".txt"]], "Input"]]
```

to accomplish the same thing the second function is trying to do. But this doesn't generalize. I want to be able to manipulate the code (and strings within the code) that is to be generated, inside the body of `Module`, and then `CellPrint` exactly the code I want.

---

**EDIT**

J.M.'s answer prompted me to ask a [more general version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271091/how-to-convert-any-string-of-code-to-an-input-cell) of this question, and the answer given there is particularly simple and elegant. It solves the problem of converting any arbitrary string of code into an input cell.

Comment: Use With, e.g. `With[{file = filename <> ".txt"}, CellPrint[...]]`

Answer (score 6):

You should just use `With` instead of `Module`, as [Carl Woll suggests](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271070/how-to-generate-input-cells-whose-code-is-determined-dynamically#comment676637_271070) in the comments:

```
makeImportCell[filename_] := With[{file = filename <> ".txt"},
  CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Defer[data = Import[file]], "Input"]]]
```

However, be aware that **usage of `CellPrint` for producing `"Input"` cells is [discouraged](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149558/how-to-make-the-result-of-inputform-balance-the-bracket#comment403087_149583)**:

> I'm not a huge fan of this because of the combination of `CellPrint` and the `"Input"` style. This creates Input cells which have `GeneratedCell->True` and `CellAutoOverwrite->True` (this is documented behavior of `CellPrint`). If you start using these cells for real, then you may have unpleasant side effects...like your Input cells disappearing when you evaluate inputs above them. If you really want Input cells, I'd recommend a `NotebookWrite` based solution. The equivalent formulation would be `NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[],Cell[BoxData[ToString[#, InputForm]], "Input"]] &`. – John Fultz (Jul 9, 2017 at 5:19)

To generate `"Input"` cells that behave exactly like regular user-created cells, [use](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269996/280) `NotebookWrite` instead:

```
makeImportCell[filename_] := With[{file = filename <> ".txt"},
  NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   Cell[BoxData@MakeBoxes[data = Import[file]], "Input"]]]
```

Further reading:

- [Output of code generated by CellPrint goes to the end of notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/269955/280)

Comment: If the `GeneratedCell` and `CellAutoOverwrite` options are the problem, you can also just manually set those options: `CellPrint[ExpressionCell[expr, "Input", GeneratedCell -> False, CellAutoOverwrite -> False]]`

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I tried it. My experiments showed that it doesn't allow to reproduce the behavior we get with `NotebookWrite`. I don't know what, but there seems to be something besides these options that affects this. See the last words in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269955/output-of-code-generated-by-cellprint-goes-to-the-end-of-notebook/269963?noredirect=1#comment676690_269963) comment. Also, I think John Fultz has serious reasons to recommend `NotebookWrite` instead of `CellPrint`.

Comment: I also want the generated cell to be an initialization cell, which I can do with `CellPrint[..., InitializationCell -> True]`, but not `NotebookWrite`. However, I'm not finding any overwrite issues with `CellPrint`. Maybe the default behavior was updated?

Comment: E.g., execute the following code multiple times. I get a new generated cell each time, and nothing is overwritten. `CellPrint[
 Cell[BoxData@"Module[{x}, x = 1]", "Input", 
  InitializationCell -> True]]`.

Comment: @WillG Please evaluate any but the last of generated cells to see the effect.

Comment: It still seems to work fine. Even when I evaluate any of the generated cells, everything seems normal. ?? E.g., evaluate the line of code in the most recent comment above three times, then execute the middle cell of the generated outputs.

Comment: @WillG Just tried, yes: with such simple setup it works as expected, but not with more complicated. Try the [setup](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269963/280) from the linked question: `CellPrint/@{Cell["1\n2","Input",InitializationCell->True],Cell["I'll disappear after evaluation of the previous cell!","Text"],Cell["3","Input",InitializationCell->True]};`.

Answer (score 4):

This required a bit more trickery than I would like:

```
makeImportCell[filename_] := Module[{file},
    file = filename <> ".txt";
    CellPrint[Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"data", "=", 
                                   RowBox[{"Import", "[",
                                           "\"" <> file <> "\"", "]"}]}]], 
                   "Input"]]]
```

and then evaluating `makeImportCell["fooba"]` does print a cell with `data = Import["fooba.txt"]`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like I can use a similar method to construct arbitrary output code. However, I'm not familiar with the `BoxData` and `RowBox` structure that is apparently used to encode notebook expressions. Is there a handy way to convert an already-typed notebook expression, e.g., `data=Import["filename.txt"]`, into the explicit `BoxData`/`RowBox` form you used here?

Comment: Something like `MakeBoxes[data = Import["filename.txt"], StandardForm]` would be useful for that purpose.

Comment: I might make a new post about this, but... Suppose I have some string `str` which is a valid piece of code that evaluates upon `ToExpression@str`. I can simply copy/paste the contents of this string into a new cell, and they are automatically formatted correctly. Therefore, it seems this copy/pasting action should be easy to automate with code. Is there a way to use `CellPrint` so that `str` appears in a new cell as correctly formatted code?

Comment: I like the method outlined above with `MakeBoxes`, but it still requires manually fiddling around with each particular expression. Seems like there should be a simpler way to automate the string -> input code conversion that works for arbitrary strings of (valid) code.

Comment: Made a new post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271091/how-to-convert-any-string-of-code-to-an-input-cell