# How to convert any string of code to an input cell?

Tags: notebooks, cells, input, code-generation

This is a generalization of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271070/how-to-generate-input-cells-whose-code-is-determined-dynamically#271070) question, which already has very nice answers.

Suppose `str` is a string of valid code, so that `ToExpression[str]` generates an output. I can copy/paste the contents of `str` into a cell and then evaluate this cell manually.

But I'd like to automate the process of generating an input cell containing the contents of `str`. That is, I'm looking for a function `makeCell[str_]` that generates an input cell with the contents of `str`. This seems doable because it can be done by copy/pasting, and functions like `ToExpression` and `CellPrint` exist (see above post and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144896/how-to-generate-an-input-cell?noredirect=1&lq=1) one for specific examples). But so far I haven't found a solution.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: FrontEnd will happily accept an input form string wrapped with `BoxData`:

```
NotebookWrite[
  EvaluationNotebook[]
, BoxData @ "Module[{x}, x = 1]"
]
```

Incorporate it in methods you use from previous questions.

Btw, in case it didn't accept strings:

```
NotebookWrite[
  EvaluationNotebook[]
, ToExpression["Module[{x}, x = 1]", InputForm, MakeBoxes]
]
```

Comment: Nice. This is so simple, I feel it's really the "right" answer to my linked question as well.

Comment: To make the generated cell also be an initialization cell, you can use `CellPrint[
 Cell[BoxData@"Module[{x}, x = 1]", "Input", 
  InitializationCell -> True]]`. I can't find a way to do this using `NotebookWrite`, and some people in the linked post warn against using `CellPrint` for various reasons, but it works fine for me.

Comment: @WillG NotebookWrite[Evaluation Notebook[] , Cell[... , "Input", InitializationCell->True]] ?

Comment: Whoops, forgot those options went into `Cell` and not `CellPrint`. Thanks!

Comment: For strings containing new lines I ran into an error for MakeBoxes not having the right number of arguments. I could fix it by removing the new lines but this comes at the cost of not having new lines in the produced cell and having to add them back in by hand. How would I make this robust for strings containing newlines (and multiple lines of code separated by `;`).

Comment: @Kvothe can you add an example? `"Module[{x}, x = 1];\n%+1"` this works for me on Win.