# How to programmatically create a notebook from a list of Input Cell[]'s with syntax highlighting?

Tags: export, notebooks, cells

consider the following list of Cell[]'s:

```
cells = {
         Cell[
              "foo=\"string1\";(*comment*)bar=\"string2\";"
            , "Input"
         ]
        ,Cell[
              "foo=\"string1\";(*comment*)bar=\"string2\";"
            , "Input"]
        };
nb = Notebook[{cells}];
SystemOpen@Export[$HomeDirectory <> "/notebook.nb", nb]
```

[image: d]

Using the [`Notebook`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Notebook.html) function, I can create and export a notebook, but there is no syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `BoxData` to mark it `StandardForm` as opposed to a plain text content. Notice that as soon as the notebook is created or exported the text content will be automatically converted to a box expression.

```
cells = {
   Cell["foo=\"string1\";(*comment*)bar=\"string2\";", "Input"], 
   Cell["foo=\"string1\";(*comment*)bar=\"string2\";", "Input"]
   };
nb = Notebook[MapAt[BoxData, cells, {All, 1}]];

Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "test.nb"}], nb]

NotebookOpen@%
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Is this usage of `BoxData` documented?

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I am not sure, I think I learned it from John Fultz's comments somewhere around here and I use it from time to time: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271092/5478