# How to stop opening of cell groups after evaluation of the whole Notebook?

Tags: bugs, evaluation, notebooks, cells, display

**Bug introduced in 12.3 or earlier and persisting through 13.1.0**

---

I have a long notebook with `Section`, `Subsection`, `Text`, `Code` etc.
Now when I evaluate the notebook, it expands all the cells. This causes inconvenience sometimes when you have to go to a particular section, subsection, or code since one now has to scroll a lot or close the section, or subsection manually over the course.

**Is there any way I can evaluate the notebook using the `Evaluation ► Evaluate Notebook` menu item, but keeping the closed cell groups not expanded?**

For example, I want a *closed section* to remain closed after the evaluation.

I tried unchecking the `Cell/Cell Properties/ Open`, but no luck.

---

EDIT:
This is a minimal example to show the problem with one `Section`, one
`Subsection`, one `Text`, and one `Code` cell.

[image]

Comment: What version are you using? This doesn't happen to me on 13.1/Mac.

Comment: @lericr I am using 13.1 on Linux. I always write code inside Code cell. May be this is due to this? But still not wanted.

Comment: On my setup, Input cell versus Code cell makes no difference to the open/close behavior. I guess it's a Linux "feature".

Comment: Could you check your test with two subsections?
`Section`
`Subsection-1`
`Code-1`
`Subsection-2`
`Code-2`.
And then you have something in the `Code` to evaluate. I think you will also notice. Otherwise, I can find some Mac to test this.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with that structure. If you have a very specific section structure that you think will cause this, and you think I didn't do it right, then just post that exactly, and I'll try again.

Comment: Your update clarifies the behavior, but it makes your question confusing. If the notebook has a trailing executable cell (e.g. Input), and that last executable cell is in a closed group, the group will indeed open. But your frustration seemed to be based on intermediate groups opening. You mentioned the inconvenience of having to scroll further. Only the final group opens, and then only if it's terminated with an executable cell. You can easily suppress that by adding a non-executable cell at the end. So, it doesn't seem like this accurately describes the behavior you're frustrated with.

Comment: I understand your clarification. However when I have a larger notebook with Chapters, sections and a lot of them, it’s not only the last cell which is opened rather most of them. I am not sure how can I show that behavior here, but that is similar to the example not just the last cell!

Comment: @leric is there any way to suppress this expansion unless wanted (even for the last cell)? Adding a non-executable cell seems overkill, you have to do it at the end of all sections for example!

Comment: I just don't know. I do see the "last group that has terminating input cell opens" behavior, but I don't see intermediate groups open. I really don't know what governs this. look throught the options inspector maybe? or maybe it's a cell property that you can set with styles? I can imaging that it's annoying, but I'm just not having the same experience, so have never explored this.

Comment: I observe on Windows 10 x64 very similar behavior to what @lericr observes on Mac: only the last cell group opens, and only if it has a trailing cell having `Evaluatable -> True` *and* it's previous output.  It is strange, but if the last cell group ends with an evaluatable cell without output, it doesn't open! This last observation (as well as different behavior across platforms) finally ensures me that the described behavior is a *regression bug* in the recent Mathematica versions. Added the "BUG" header and the tag. Please report it to the support.

Comment: In my case, all the cells which have output are expanded, it does not matter if they are intermediate cells or the last. Only those cells which do not have output remain closed. I don't see the above behavior when I try to replicate it with copies of dummy test like the gif above with a lot of `Title`, `Section`, `Code` but on my real example (which unfortunately I don't have any means to show it here) it happens. I will file a bug report but it will be very difficult to explain the situation there.

Comment: Obviously the behavior is both inconsistent and platform-dependent. I think providing a link to this discussion will help.

Comment: What about "Find currently evaluating cell"?

Answer (score 4):

One way to get a Notebook evaluated without side-effects like opening cell groups is do not insert the results of the evaluation into this Notebook:

```
NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> False];
```

In this case all the cells in the Notebook `nb` will be evaluated without changing the `nb` in any way. You can apply this method even to the `EvaluationNotebook[]` itself, but in this case a little trick is necessary to prevent infinite recursion:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], Evaluatable -> False];
NotebookEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[], InsertResults -> False];
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], Evaluatable -> True];
```

Another option I just discovered is to put at the end of the cell group a cell with `Evaluatable -> False` (for example, it may be a usual `"Text"` cell or a [Horizontal Line](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/HorizontalLines.html) *Object*). In this case after using the menu item `Evaluation ► Evaluate Notebook` the results of evaluation will be inserted without opening the cell group where they will appear. I found this with *Mathematica* version 13.1 on Windows 10 x64.

It is also interesting that with *Mathematica* version 8.0.4 the cell groups won't be opened even without a trailing cell with `Evaluatable -> False`. Hence this behavior is new in the recent versions, and may be unintentional (a consequence of a bug). I recommend reporting this to the official support with a reference to this answer.

---

**Further discussion**

On Windows 10 x64 I observe something very similar to what [lericr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/84894/lericr) [observes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271400/how-to-stop-the-expansion-of-input-cells-after-the-evaluation/271426#comment677627_271400) on Mac: if a Notebook contains several closed cell groups containing evaluatable cells, **only the last cell group opens** after `Evaluation ► Evaluate Notebook`, **but only if this last cell group ends with an evaluatable cell *and* it's sole output**. It is strange, but if the last cell group ends with an evaluatable cell *without output* or *with two or more output cells*, it doesn't open! This last observation finally ensures me that the described behavior is a *regression bug* in the recent *Mathematica* versions. Please report it to the support.

From the observation that the last cell group opens only if it has a trailing evaluatable cell *with an output cell*, comes a workaround: before evaluating the Notebook, just delete all the output using the `Cell ► Delete All Output` menu item, and only then execute `Evaluation ► Evaluate Notebook`. This method can easily be automatized:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], Evaluatable -> False];
FrontEndTokenExecute["DeleteGeneratedCells"];
FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluateNotebook"];
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], Evaluatable -> True];
```

A nice feature of the `Cell ► Delete All Output` menu item is that it deletes the cells having `GeneratedCell -> True` *only immediately following  a cell with `Evaluatable -> True`*, and doesn't delete standalone cells with `GeneratedCell -> True` (which you possibly have manually created by copying). This method won't have an impact on the performance, because in any case after evaluation of a cell it's [existing output is removed before inserting the newly generated output](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269996/280) (even if the new ouput is `Null`, i.e. no output cell will be created).

However, if a cell prints something using `CellPrint` or `NotebookWrite` (but not `Print`!), the target cell group will be expanded in any case. This aspect of behavior is the same as in version 8.0.4.